# Golang 1.7 context value nil

Tags: http, go, jwt, middleware

I'm trying to implement a JWT (JSON web token) middleware using Go's 1.7 context package, but I'm running into a strange bug retrieving an earlier set context value..

Given the code..

```
func JWTAuthenticator(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := r.Context()
        jwtToken, _ := ctx.Value("jwt").(*jwt.Token)

        fmt.Printf("ctx = %+v\n", ctx)
        fmt.Printf("ctx = %+v\n", jwtToken)

        // Token is authenticated, pass it through
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

This returns ..

```
context.Background.WithValue(&http.contextKey{name:"http-server"}, &http.Server{Addr:":8080", Handler:(*chi.Mux)(0xc4201ec180), ReadTimeout:0, WriteTimeout:0, TLSConfig:(*tls.Config)(0xc420210000), MaxHeaderBytes:0, TLSNextProto:map[string]func(*http.Server, *tls.Conn, http.Handler){"h2-14":(func(*http.Server, *tls.Conn, http.Handler))(0xb8410), "h2":(func(*http.Server, *tls.Conn, http.Handler))(0xb8410)}, ConnState:(func(net.Conn, http.ConnState))(nil), ErrorLog:(*log.Logger)(nil), disableKeepAlives:0, nextProtoOnce:sync.Once{m:sync.Mutex{state:0, sema:0x0}, done:0x1}, nextProtoErr:error(nil)}).WithValue(&http.contextKey{name:"local-addr"}, &net.TCPAddr{IP:net.IP{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, Port:8080, Zone:""}).WithCancel.WithCancel.WithValue(&chi.contextKey{name:"RouteContext"}, &chi.Context{URLParams:chi.params(nil), RoutePath:"", RoutePattern:"/store", RoutePatterns:[]string{"/store"}}).WithValue(0, "us2-ldn-barlow/XJoT7aahzI-000001").WithValue("jwt", &jwt.Token{Raw:"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdG9yZV9pZCI6NzA4MDJ9.eT70KOJbS4JJrsMC76KH4IPRozPt-ipjMDUSuAUhB4k", Method:(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC)(0xc420133d80), Header:map[string]interface {}{"alg":"HS256", "typ":"JWT"}, Claims:map[string]interface {}{"store_id":70802}, Signature:"eT70KOJbS4JJrsMC76KH4IPRozPt-ipjMDUSuAUhB4k", Valid:true}).WithValue("jwt.err", <nil>)

ctx = <nil>
```

Which as you can does include a value .WithValue("jwt") but is returning nil!

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe don't ignore the second value from the type conversion `jwtToken, _ :=`.

Comment: It's possible the types do not match - if you set the value with a `type key string` ala the context package example, then "jwt" won't match.  Cannot tell from your code...  If you have indeed made a new type, then simply create a package accessor - https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/context/context.go#L129

Answer (score 3):

I eventually found the issues.

The two types were the same `jwt.Token` however one type was from a vendored package in the imported library and one was from the package in my GOPATH. Although the same package and the type, Go had an issue casting and comparing these types!

To fix, I use a vendoring tool `govendor` and ran `govendor add +external` which mean that both packages now used the same import

Comment: You are a hero and should get a badge for it. To come back and update the few people who may run into this unexpected clash.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the library the wrote to the context has a vendored copy of the shared library (that had keys in the context) and the main library also needed to vendor the same shared library to be able to look the values associated with thoee keys up,

As an alternative to using `govendor` or if you are using other vendoring methods ( I use `gvt`), you can just manually delete the copy that the vondored library has vendored inside of itself,